# JTable RowFilter - case insensitive

Tags: java, regex, swing, jtable, rowfilter

I'm having a problem with a `RowFilter`, I'm trying to make it display data without it being case sensitive.

```
DefaultTableModel table=(DefaultTableModel)tablicaEv.getModel();
String search=jTextField1.getText();
TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr=new TableRowSorter<> (table);
tablicaEv.setRowSorter(tr);
tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(search);
```

I tried adding "(?!)" in the `RegexFilter` but that only makes my table not display any data at all when I try searching. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably wanted to prefix the search string with `(?i)` (case insensitive match) - `(?!)` is a "zero-width negative lookahead" matching nothing.

Comment: I feel so stupid now hah, haven't even realized. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanted to prefix the search string with `(?i)` (case insensitive match).

`(?!)` is a "zero-width negative lookahead" matching nothing which will never match if anything follows it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    public static RowFilter<Object, Object> getCaseInsensitiveRowFilter(String text, int... indexes) {
        if (com.csii.cide.base.util.StringUtil.isBlank(text)) {
            return null;
        }
        List<RowFilter<Object, Object>> filters = Lists.newArrayList();
        filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(text.toUpperCase(), indexes));
        filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(text.toLowerCase(), indexes));
        return RowFilter.orFilter(filters);
    }
```